# Angular 10 - Insert data using Redux

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-redux, angular-state-managmement

I am using redux to perform "CRUD" operations.

In my `student.reduce.ts` file, I have this code to generate a new register:

```js
 case StudentsActionTypes.CreateStudentSucceeded:
     let studentNew = [];
 let s = state.students;
 studentNew.push(action.student);
 return {
     ...state,
     students: studentNew,
     isLoading: false,
 };
```

The object `state.students` contains the existing data and `action.student` contains the new data, when I do the insert, it visually generates the new record, but I lose the old data, how can I merge `state.students` and `action .student` to display all data visually.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
case StudentsActionTypes.CreateStudentSucceeded:
return {
  ...state,
  students: [...state.students, action.student],
  isLoading: false,
};
```